# URL path for objects that may include 'null' objects

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a URL path defined like this:

```
# Page for a single label.
path('labels/<str:label_name>/', views.label, name='label'),
```

However, the 'label' field is optional (blank=True, null=True), so there are inevitably cases where there is no label name.  I'm wondering how I can work around this - is there a way to change the definition of 'label' in the models.py file that would do the trick?  Some sort of 'if' statement in the `def __str__(self):` part?
This is the 'label' definition:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    """The label a song was released on."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the model object."""
       return self.name
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry - the problem turned out to be in my HTML template - I needed to include an 'if' statement for null objects:

```
{% for label in labels %}
      {% if label.name and label.name.strip %}
          <li>
              <a href="{% url 'great_songs:label' label.name %}">{{ label }}</a>
          </li>
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In your url you have `lebel_name`, is that present in model?